# how to create an ArrayList to generate from 0 to 255?

Tags: java, arrays, list, random

I am using Java/Eclipse.

I don't understand/know how to put these two codes together to answer the following questions:

1. Create a method `RandomArray` that takes in as parameter an integer n and returns a `ArrayList` of Integers (`ArrayList<Integer>`) that consists of n random numbers between `0` and `255` (i.e. the returned array is of size `n`). Appendix A contains some example code that might be useful.
2. Create a method `ShowArray` that takes in as a parameter an `ArrayList` of Integers (`ArrayList<Integer>`) and displays the contents of the `ArrayList`.
3. Test these two methods, i.e. create a random list and then display it.

Here is the code so far:

```
    private static ArrayList<Integer> CopyArray(ArrayList<Integer> a)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> resa = new ArrayList<Integer>(a.size());
            for(int i=0;i<a.size();++i) resa.add(a.get(i));
            return(resa);
        }
        public static ArrayList<Integer> SortA(ArrayList<Integer> a)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
            int n = a.size(),i;
            boolean noswaps = false;

            while (noswaps == false)
            {
                noswaps = true;
                for(i=0;i<n-1;++i)
                {
                    if (array.get(i) < array.get(i+1))
                    {
                        Integer temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i,array.get(i+1));
                        array.set(i+1,temp);
                        noswaps = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return(array);
        }
```

and

```
    ArrayList<Integer> randomArrayList;int n = 255;
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            list.add(new Integer(random.nextInt(255)));
        }
       System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Tag a programming language on this questions.

Comment: ArrayList<...> shouldn't have brackets `{` `}` coming out of it.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424482/return-an-arraylist-of-integers-that-consist-of-n-random-numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> randomArray(int n) { ... }
private static void showArray(ArrayList<Integer> a) { ... }
private static void test() {
    int n = 13;
    ArrayList<Integer> a = randomArray(n);
    showArray(a);
}
```

You already did too much; return does not need braces.

Comment: why can't i answer again with code in my comments?   I am getting errors while trying to run.