# how to create an immutable iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

If I have a Map or a List and get an iterator from it, for example:

```
var map = new HashMap();
var iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

if something modifies that map after the fact, will it affect the iterator or is the iterator basically immutable once created?

*If it's not immutable, how to create an immutable iterator?*

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081318/can-a-iterator-change-the-collection-it-is-iterating-over-java?

Comment: related but my question is probably better worded and more to the point

Comment: why -1? I think that is an interesting question?

Comment: Please **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html): *"The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are **fail-fast**: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` method, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`."*

Comment: OK let's think outside the box - how to create an immutable iterator? Come on people. The documentation might be clear if you dig, but I am looking for a way to create an immutable iterator once it's created.

Comment: Updated the OP for those who can't read between the lines...

Comment: You would, I think, need to design a `Collection` from the ground up with an eye toward supporting these so-called "immutable" iterators.  A collection instance would need to be aware at all times of every `Iterator` instance in existence and be able to notify those `Iterator` instances of every structural modification in sufficient detail that the `Iterator` could figure out how to proceed.  And, of course, the `Iterator`s themselves would have to be sufficiently resourceful to make sense of any possible change notification that might be thrown their way.

Comment: The question as phrased doesn't really make sense, as iterators are inherently necessarily mutable; if I understand correctly, you want an iterator that's a snapshot of the underlying collection at some moment in time?

Comment: Also, see the documentation for `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which I think implements what you're asking for.

Comment: @chrylis CopyOnWriteArrayList makes a new copy for every add() operation, etc, that's not quite what I am looking for

Comment: @chrylis Iterators are not more "inherently necessarily mutable" as a concept than collections (containers).

Comment: @chrylis @chrylis Consider that C++ has `const_iterator` types (for referring to `const` values) and can have `const iterator` values (for iterators that can not be incremented).

Comment: @Raedwald This is a question relating to Java and the term should be interpreted in its context. Your `const iterator` does not match the description in the question.

Answer (score 2):

An iterator instance itself would not generally need the concept of mutability/immutability. However, the collection it is iterating over may be intended to be unmodifiable or immutable. Here is a way to disable the ability of an iterator to change the collection. If you return an instance of this class, then the remove() method of the returned iterator is disabled. The class is used by returning UnmodifiableIterator.create(yourIterator).

```
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * UnmodifiableIterator, A wrapper around an iterator instance that
 * disables the remove method.
 */
public final class UnmodifiableIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    /**
     * iterator, The base iterator.
     */
    private final Iterator<? extends E> iterator;

    private UnmodifiableIterator(final Iterator<? extends E> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public static <E> Iterator<E> create(final Iterator<? extends E> iterator) {
        if (iterator == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The iterator can not be null.");
        }
        return new UnmodifiableIterator<>(iterator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        return iterator.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Iterator.remove() is disabled.");
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is pretty much the same as Apache common collection's UnmodifiableIterator. Ref: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/jacoco/org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators/UnmodifiableIterator.java.html

Answer (score 1):

The only valid operations for a read-only iterator are increment and dereference (although the Java `Iterator` combines the two in its [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()) method). If you have an unmodifiable iterator, that leaves you only dereferencing. The dereferencing can either give you an object reference, or it can be not valid to dereference because it does not refer to a valid position in the collection.

But those are the same semantics as [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html): an `Optional` can either be empty or have a valid object reference. So, create an `Optional` from the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and use that as your "unmodifiable iterator":

```
private Optional<T> unmodifiableNext(Iterator<T> i)
{
   if (i.hasNext()) {
      return Optional.ofNullable(i.next());
   } else {
      return Optional.empty();
   }
}
```

This has the additional benefit that the `Optional` is no longer tied to the collection, so the collection can be safely changed without changing which object the `Optional`  refers to.